# Open source writing software with version control

Tags: software, tools

I was wondering if there were any open source (free also works) writing software that includes version control (e.g. git). I'm thinking of writing my own but I don't want to create something that already exists. Everything I look for is either paid or is restricted to one or two OSs.

Also I'm planning to write this for the browser i.e. HTML, JavaScript with PHP as the backend.

NOTE:

This is not about *is there version control*. I want to create an interactive software where you can create a JSON file full of character names and you can just write a generic name in e.g. `${characters.protagonist.firstname} ${characters.protagonist.lastname}` and it'll fill it in e.g. `Harry Potter`.

Also when you do that, their names will lighten up allowing you to redirect or shows a pop up with the character details.

Comment: What's wrong with git?

Comment: @Alexander Nothing, but writing in JUST a plain txt file is just absurd. I'm going to make it so that I can create a character page, link that into the story format so that their names light up and I can click on them to access their details (like if I forget if they have tattoos or piercings). It's to make the writing format easier. Also since I'm terrible with naming I want to be able to write something like ${characters.protagonist.firstname} which then their first name shows up (in the event I feel like changing their name.

Comment: You're asking about version control but you seem to be describing using variables in your source document.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm planning to create my own open source software. I just wanted to see if there was anything like it at the moment so I wouldn't waste my time creating something that already exists and use it instead. So I'm looking for something that can do version control, as well as easily insert characters/locations from pre-defined variables and it has to be free.

Comment: I believe this to be more common in screenwriting (see [Trelby](http://www.trelby.org) and [Fountain](https://fountain.io/)). I also remember [ChoiceScript](https://www.choiceofgames.com/make-your-own-games/choicescript-intro/) for text based games. Its not an answer but it might give you some ideas. [Atom](https://atom.io/) is also pretty good for customization.

Comment: @armatita Yeah, I use Atom for programming, but have not found any packages that do what I want (don't think it was created with that intention). Took a look at Trelby and Fountain but they're for screenwriting, so I'm not sure if it's that appropriate.

Comment: Atom is a general purpose Text Editor (see [Writer](https://atom.io/packages/Writer)) although admittedly its mainly used in programming . Just search for words like "Atom for Writers" and you'll get a bunch of articles with several available packages for this purpose ([example 1](https://opensource.com/article/17/5/atom-text-editor-packages-writers), [example 2](https://ben.balter.com/2016/12/23/atom-for-prose/), [example 3](https://www.daveyshafik.com/archives/70014-authoring-with-the-atom-text-editor.html)).

Comment: If you're comfortable with command line software development tools you could always use a version control system like Git alongside any text editor you fancy

Comment: @GordonM I do, but I'd like more than that. I'd like to be able to drop characters in and out kind of stuff and quick searches. Like character names are highlighted so that when you click on them a box pops up with their details you've saved elsewhere. I'm probably going to try and write this in electron, since I can't find anything like it (also will be a good learning experience).

Comment: @A.Lau Hmm, it almost sounds like you might benefit from some kind of wiki software?  Again if you're comfortable with it you could always try setting something like MediaWiki up in a virtual machine

Comment: Please create a plugin for your favorite editor, don't write something from scratch

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing some research into free and open source software for writers.  The most promising candidates so far, in no particular order, are:

[yWriter](http://www.spacejock.com/yWriter5.html)

> yWriter is a word processor which breaks your novel into chapters and scenes, helping you keep track of your work while leaving your mind free to create.

[bibisco](http://www.bibisco.com/)

> Organize chapters and scenes, manage revisions, export novel in pdf or rtf. And, of course, write with a fully featured text editor.

[Manuskript](http://www.theologeek.ch/manuskript/)

> Manuskript is a perfect tool for those writer who like to organize and plan everything before writing.
>   The snowflake method can help you grow your idea into a book, by leading you step by step and asking you questions to go deeper.
>   While writing, keep track of notes about every characters, plot, event, place in your story.

[Plume Creator](http://plume-creator.eu/)

> This software gives you an outliner, a distraction-free mode, a note manager and much more!

[oStorybook](http://ostorybook.tuxfamily.org/?lng=en)

> open source software for writers, essayists, authors. Used from the draft to the final work, with oStorybook you can never lose the history of the field of view. oStorybook helps you to maintain control over the various developments of your story.

A comparison and more in-depth reviews can be found here https://crawfordwriting.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/free-scrivener-alternatives/

I'm not sure yet which have in-built version control, but any of these in conjunction with a version control system might provide the solution you are after, before you embark on your own project.

Comment: manuskript looks pretty good, may give it a run